Checking for errors in Ruby Net::HTTP::Get or Post when streaming the response?
I'm trying to read a streaming request using Net::HTTP. I get the response and check that I have a 200. What happens if the stream errors while I'm processing chunks? How do I get that error?
http_request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(path_with_query, headers)
Net::HTTP.start(host, port, connect_opts) do |http|
  http.request(http_request) do |response|
    if response.code != "200"
      raise "error #{response.code}"
    end
    response.read_body do |chunk|
      next unless chunk.length > 0
      @block.call(chunk)
    end
  end
end

Each time response.read_body calls the block, there is a chance that there has been an error. Will the response object be updated with the error, or do I have to do something else?

If there is an error like a bad chunk length or the socket closes, that error will be raised inside the read_body block. This does not change the HTTP status code but rather ruby will raise the error. If you need to trap this error in some way I would recommend wrapping the entire response.read_body call in a begin...rescue and handle it that way.

Pro tip: instead of doing if response.code != "200" use a case statement with ranges of HTTP codes. case response.code.to_is; when 200..299; ....

@max Since every Net::HTTPResponse is actually a distinct subclass based on the status code. I think using the response class is more communicative e.g. case response; when Net::HTTPSuccess
